# http://showmyip.pw/badwebsite/example.com URL in Stats

Tags: seo, url, spam

I've been seeing http://showmyip.pw/badwebsite/ with my valid URL's on the end of it (happening on all my sites)

```
http://showmyip.pw/badwebsite/example.com
```

Does anyone know what this is about?

A quick look on Whois.com shows that

```
http://showmyip.pw
```

Is in fact a valid website being served up by Cloudflare that shows your IP address, however put

```
/badwebsite/
```

after it and it quickly transfers over to some advertising site.  I do not want to give them the satisfaction of going to the URLs in my stats.

Just wondering if anyone knows is it just ghost referrer spam or something more sinister, is it bad for SEO & should I block them in htaccess?

Comment: Another junk site. Do not worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is "[referrer spam](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spam)". Ignore it.